# Child elements z-index not working when parents are fixed and have the same z-index?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I used [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/qL0rpjfv/2/) to recreate my issue. I would like .top .inside to be above .bottom .inside. I know that z-index only works with its respective position type i.e. fixed and absolute don't occupy the same z-index state, but If I have both fixed parents with the same z-index, is there a way to have the children positioned absolute with differing z-indexes depending on which I want on top? Even if I have to use jQuery/javascript?

html:

```
<body>
    <div class="fixed top">
        <div class="inside">I am inside a fixed element</div>
    </div>
    <div class="fixed bottom">
        <div class="inside">I am inside a fixed element</div>
  </div>
</body>
```

css:

```
.fixed {
  margin: auto;
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 111;
}
.top {
  background: #222;
  height: 150px;
  top: 0;
}
.bottom {
  background: #555;
  height: 58px;
  top: 100px;
}
.inside {
  background: #770000;
  margin: auto;
  padding: 20px;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 200px;
}
.top .inside {
  background: #770000;
  top: 70px;
  z-index: 999;
}
.bottom .inside {
  background: #007700;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right now both elements are siblings, so they are in the same stacking context. However, they also are both getting their z-index from the `.fixed` class, which is `111`.

To see `top` above, you need the to add a z-index higher than 111:

```
.top {
  background: #222;
  height: 150px;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 112;
}
```

Edit:

Positioned elements create their own stacking contexts, where everything within that context is z-indexed relative to the base node. So, because both parent elements are positioned, they create a stacking context. Therefore, the zindexes of the things inside them won't be relative across contexts, and will instead as a whole context be delegated to by the topmost node.

[My favorite article on the subject](http://philipwalton.com/articles/what-no-one-told-you-about-z-index/)

Comment: So by having the same z-index with both parents I can't alter what is inside them? No javascript/jQuery way to do it either?

Comment: by having parents with the same z-index, you won't be able to make select children overlap children of the other without making the whole parent overlap the other.
 the article spells out the rules of precedence pretty well. if two siblings have same z-index, then it's further down the page i beliebe is shown above.

Comment: Good article. Thanks for that.

Answer (score 2):

Add a `z-index` to bottom. Works like you want it to.

```css
.fixed {
  margin: auto;
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 111;
}
.top {
  background: #222;
  height: 150px;
  top: 0;
}
.bottom {
  background: #555;
  height: 58px;
  top: 100px;
  z-index:1;
}
.inside {
  background: #770000;
  margin: auto;
  padding: 20px;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 200px;
}
.top .inside {
  background: #770000;
  top: 70px;
  z-index: 999;
}
.bottom .inside {
  background: #007700;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<body>
 <div class="fixed top">
  <div class="inside">I am inside a fixed element</div>
 </div>
 <div class="fixed bottom">
  <div class="inside">I am inside a fixed element</div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: The point was to have both parents be the same z-index, but I think I might just lower the .bottom z-index and figure a work around with what I am trying to accomplish. Thank you for your answer.